# WebRTC never fires onIceCandidate

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I started developing with WebRTC, but that thing never gives me ICE candidates. I set up everything, I'm exchanging the descriptions and stuff, I also made a super-ugly function narrow down there to make sure everything runs correctly, one after another. Signaling state is stable for both, *onError* is never fired (as expected), but onIceCandidate also (not as expected), and when I want to send a random, empty MediaStream object `pc1.addStream(new webkitMediaStream());`, it always fires *onNegotiationNeeded*.

Does anyone have an idea what the heck is wrong with my code? I spent hours of browsing Stack Overflow, HTML5 Rocks, and W3C docs, but I don't understand that. Here is my entire code:

```
var config={
  'iceServers':[{
    'url':'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
  },{
    'url':'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'
  },{
    'url':'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'
  },{
    'url':'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'
  },{
    'url':'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'
  }]
};
var pc1=new webkitRTCPeerConnection(config);
var pc2=new webkitRTCPeerConnection(config);

var onError=function(error)
{
  console.error(error);
}

pc1.onicecandidate=function()
{
  console.log('PC1 onIceCandidate (finally) fired!');
}
pc2.onicecandidate=function()
{
  console.log('PC2 onIceCandidate (finally) fired!');
}

pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange=function()
{
  console.log('PC1 oniceconnectionstatechange fired!');
}
pc2.oniceconnectionstatechange=function()
{
  console.log('PC2 oniceconnectionstatechange fired!');
}
pc1.onnegotiationneeded=function()
{
  console.log('PC1 onnegotiationneeded fired!');
}
pc2.onnegotiationneeded=function()
{
  console.log('PC2 onnegotiationneeded fired!');
}

pc1.createOffer(function(offer){
  pc1.setLocalDescription(offer,function(){
    pc2.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer),function(){
      pc2.createAnswer(function(answer){
        pc2.setLocalDescription(answer,function(){
          pc1.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer),new Function()/*I don't need you, bro*/,onError);
        },onError);
      },onError);
    },onError);
  },onError);
},onError);
```

BTW I'm developing with Google Chrome. I will make sure it also runs in Firefox, but right now the problem should be cross-browser. I want to make it to data channels before... (but I have nothing against a working solution with Firefox or cross-browser code)

Comment: OT; Now as I see this code, I know why they've invented JS promises…

Comment: Instead of editing an update into your question, you might want to [post an actual answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (and then rollback your edit)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I didn't know that it's possible... I'm a bit new here, usually I only read this site

Comment: Note that callbacks are considered legacy now. RTCPeerConnection [supports promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer#Syntax) in all browsers.

Comment: I'd also consider most of the question itself legacy now. Can't believe I wrote this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Chrome 38 and earlier, `OfferToReceiveAudio` defaulted to `true`. Starting from Chrome 39, `OfferToReceiveAudio` defaults to false, as announced by a WebRTC engineer at [PSA: Behavior change to PeerConnection.createOffer constraint OfferToReceiveAudio](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/DflzuISwjrM/Y48-Hw1QnU0J) (quoted below).
Because of this change, the SDP returned by `createOffer` does not contain any media, and therefore the ICE gathering process never starts. You can notice the consequences of this change by observing that the ICE events are never triggered, and the PeerConnection's `iceGatheringState` and `iceConnectionState` stay "new".

To make sure that the ICE gathering starts and complete, you have to add media to your offer, e.g. by setting `OfferToReceiveAudio:true` in the following constraints to your offer (either as a parameter of the [`PeerConnection` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#Constructor), or as a parameter to the [`peerConnection.createOffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#createOffer) method):

```
{
    mandatory: {
        OfferToReceiveAudio: true
    }
}
```

(other ways to get media in the SDP include setting `OfferToReceiveVideo:true`, or calling [`peerConnection.addStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/WebRTC_basics#addStream) with a media stream that you got from `getUserMedia`)

---

webrtc-discuss: [PSA: Behavior change to PeerConnection.createOffer constraint OfferToReceiveAudio](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/DflzuISwjrM/Y48-Hw1QnU0J):

> I'm going to submit a change (https://webrtc-codereview.appspot.com/16309004/) to change the behavior of RTCPeerConnection.createOffer. 
>   The change is expected to be included in Chrome M39.
>
> **What's changed:**
>
> Currently if the OfferToReceiveAudio constraint is not specified in PeerConnection.createOffer, the resulted offer SDP will have an "m=audio" line even if there is no audio track attached to the PeerConnection. In other words, OfferToReceiveAudio defaults to true.
>
> After my change, OfferToReceiveAudio no longer defaults to true. Whether the offer SDP has an "m=audio" line depends on if any audio track has been attached to the PeerConnection.
>
> **What's not changed:**
>
> The behavior of setting an explicit value for OfferToReceiveAudio remains the same, i.e. OfferToReceiveAudio:true will result in an "m=audio" line regardless of the existence of audio tracks; OfferToReceiveAudio:false will result in no "m=audio" line regardless of the existence of audio tracks, unless setLocalDescription has been called with an SDP containing an "m=audio" line, in which case the new offer SDP will mark the audio content inactive instead of removing the audio content.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the `PeerConnection` constructor anymore, but works in the `peerConnection.createOffer` method. (Chrome 44)

Comment: Note that this answer is [outdated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30982333/918910). The right syntax is `{offerToReceiveAudio: true}` (no `mandatory`, and lower-case `o`).

Comment: Hello from the future...this was extremely helpful, thank you. I'd like to mention that `offerToReceiveAudio` is legacy now according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer#RTCOfferOptions_dictionary I haven't found another workaround, but this got my ice candidates to generate (I'm doing video not audio).

Comment: Spent 3 hours trying to find out why `onicecandidateerror` `oniceconnectionstatechange` `onicegatheringstatechange` `onicecandidate` wasn't being called. I also saw that it was marked as legacy, but it was the only way to get it to work in Chrome.

Comment: This answer save my life

Answer (score 6):

The [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27758788/8014724) solution of Rob W from Jan 3 '15 worked for me at first but led to another problem.
 I included `{'offerToReceiveAudio':true,'offerToReceiveVideo':true}` in the `createOffer` and `createAnswer` calls and `onIceCandidate` was called as described.
However, if I got it right, `offerToReceive...` means to **only** receive but not to send a stream. I figured that out because of the `a=recvonly` in the sdp offer and the `a=sendonly` in the sdp answer. As a result, only the caller could see the callees video but not vice versa.

As Rob states correctly:

> other ways to get media in the SDP include [...] calling peerConnection.addStream with a
>   media stream that you got from getUserMedia

Adding the stream was what I had done already in the first place. However, my sending of the sdp happened before that adding because my logical flow was mixed up. Bringing that into the right order (`addStream -> sdp = getLocalDescription -> send(sdp)`) and removing the offerOptions did the trick for me.
Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 5):

Solution in 2020

You have to do 2 things:

- include `offerToReceiveAudio` and `offerToReceiveVideo` when create `RTCPeerConnection`
- add `addTrack`

Sample code:

```js
const peerConnection= new RTCPeerConnection({
  configuration: {
    offerToReceiveAudio: true,
    offerToReceiveVideo: true
  },
  iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }]
})

localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
  peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream)
})

const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer()
await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer)

peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
  if (event.candidate) {
    console.log('Ice candidate: ', event.candidate)

  }
}

... other codes
```

Comment: This did not work with me in 2021 ! I needed to add the config explicitly to the createAnswer method (const answerDescription = await pc.createAnswer({offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true});)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If you add this code after the config declaration:

```
var mediaConstraints = {
  optional: [],
  mandatory: {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
  }
};
```

and modify the last line like this

```
},onError,mediaConstraints);
```

it just works. Don't ask me why.

Comment: Magic code isn't helpful and is terrible practice. Always ask why.

Answer (score 0):

The doc page should be used as the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer

```
const offerOptions = {
    offerToReceiveAudio: true,
    offerToReceiveVideo: true
}

myPeerConnection.createOffer ( offerOptions )
```