# Not receiving video, onicecandidate is not executing

Tags: javascript, webrtc

So I was following [this tutorial](http://web-engineering.info/node/57) to learn how to implement a WebRTC server-client setup. Once I got that working I wanted to split the client into two parts, one sender and one receiver. Now they can establish a connection with each other but the receiver never gets the stream from the sender.

I managed to determine that the code flow between the original code and split versions remains the same, except that neither peer executes the onicecandidate event.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489881/webrtc-never-fires-onicecandidate) I need to explicitly include `OfferToReceiveAudio: true` and `OfferToReceiveVideo: true` since I'm using Chrome, which I did but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Currently, they both receive SDP from each other, there is a local and remote description in the peerConnection, and `iceGatheringState` is "new" but `iceConnectionState` is "checking" (unlike the second link where he states it should also be "new")

How come they aren't exchanging ICE candidates when it's split in two like this?

### Sender.js

```js
const HTTPSPort = 3434;
const domain = '127.0.0.1';
const wssHost = 'wss://' + domain + ':' + HTTPSPort + '/websocket/';

// Feed settings
const video = true;
const audio = true;
const constraints = { "audio": audio, "video": video };

var videoContainer = null, feed = null,
 pC = null, wsc = new WebSocket(wssHost),
 pCConfig = [
  { 'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com' },
  { 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }
 ];

function pageReady() {
 // Check browser WebRTC availability
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
  videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoFeed');

  // Get the feed and show it in the local video element
  feed = stream;
  videoContainer.srcObject = feed;
 }).catch(function () {
  alert("Sorry, your browser does not support WebRTC!");
 });
}

wsc.onmessage = function (evt) {
 if (!pC) {
  // Initiate peerConnection
  pC = new RTCPeerConnection(pCConfig);

  // Send any ice candidates to the other peer
  pC.onicecandidate = onIceCandidateHandler;

  pC.addStream(feed);
 }

 // Read the message
 var signal = JSON.parse(evt.data);
 if (signal.sdp) {
  log('Received SDP from remote peer.');
  pC.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp));

  answerCall();
 } else if (signal.candidate) {
  log('Received ICECandidate from remote peer.');
  pC.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate));
 }
};

function answerCall() {
 pC.createAnswer().then(function (answer) {
  var ans = new RTCSessionDescription(answer);
  pC.setLocalDescription(ans).then(function () {
   wsc.send(JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': ans }));
  }).catch(errorHandler);
 }).catch(errorHandler);
}

function onIceCandidateHandler(evt) {
 if (!evt || !evt.candidate) return;

 wsc.send(JSON.stringify({ 'candidate': evt.candidate }));
};
```

### Receiver.js

```js
const HTTPSPort = 3434;
const domain = '127.0.0.1';
const wssHost = 'wss://' + domain + ':' + HTTPSPort + '/websocket/';

var remoteVideo = null,
 pC = null, wsc = new WebSocket(wssHost),
 pCConfig = [
  { 'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com' },
  { 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }
 ],
 mediaConstraints = {
  mandatory: {
   OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
   OfferToReceiveVideo: true
  }
 };

function pageReady() {
 remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
 icebutton = document.getElementById('checkICE');
 icebutton.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  console.log(pC);
 })
};

wsc.onopen = function () {
 // Initiates peerConnection
 pC = new RTCPeerConnection(pCConfig);

 // Send any ICE candidates to the other peer
 pC.onicecandidate = onIceCandidateHandler;

 // Once remote stream arrives, show it in the remote video element
 pC.onaddstream = onAddStreamHandler;

 // Offer a connection to the server
 createAndSendOffer();
};

function createAndSendOffer() {
 pC.createOffer(mediaConstraints).then(function (offer) {
  var off = new RTCSessionDescription(offer);
  pC.setLocalDescription(off).then(function () {
   wsc.send(JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': off }));
  }).catch(errorHandler);
 }).catch(errorHandler);
}

wsc.onmessage = function (evt) {
 // Read the message
 var signal = JSON.parse(evt.data);

 if (signal.sdp) {
  console.log('Received SDP from remote peer.');
  pC.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp));
 } else if (signal.candidate) {
  console.log('Received ICECandidate from remote peer.');
  pC.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate));
 }
};

function onIceCandidateHandler(evt) {
 if (!evt || !evt.candidate) return;

 wsc.send(JSON.stringify({ 'candidate': evt.candidate }));
};

function onAddStreamHandler(evt) {
 // Set remote video stream as source for remote video HTML element
 remoteVideo.srcObject = evt.stream;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot `iceServers`. Change

```
pCConfig = [
    { 'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com' },
    { 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }
];
```

to

```
pCConfig = {
    iceServers: [
        { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }
    ]
};
```

#### Additionally:

- `url` has [been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260021/918910), use `urls`.
- The mozilla stun server has been [decommissioned](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1143827), so save yourself some time and exclude it.
- `mandatory` and `OfferToReceiveAudio` have [been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982333/918910). Use `offerToReceiveAudio`.
- `mandatory` and `OfferToReceiveVideo` have [been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982333/918910). Use `offerToReceiveVideo`.

#### Tips

Kudos for using promises (unlike the tutorial)! Note you can [return them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084467/918910) to flatten things:

```
function createAndSendOffer() {
    return pC.createOffer(mediaConstraints).then(function (offer) {
        return pC.setLocalDescription(offer);
    })
    .then(function () {
        wsc.send(JSON.stringify({ sdp: pC.localDescription }));
    })
    .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my issue.


I could have sworn that I got an error that told me to remove `iceServers`, which is why I did...

Also, thank you for going through the effort of telling me about everything that has been depricated, "sourced" even.